# How to learn to implement a simple compiler step by step

Tags: compiler-construction

I want to implement a simple compiler by myself,but I don't know how to start.
I need a concise way to do it step by step or some good resource.
Thank you~
(I have learned C/C++, python, obj-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this invaluable:

http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/

He uses pascal but the theory is the same. Use google there is plenty of resource out there.

Comment: thanks~ good resource

Comment: Better formatted PDF: http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/compiler.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the book 'Modern Compiler Implementation' http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/